# Scanner input string appearing as null java

Tags: java, input, null

My code is here:

```
package test1;
import java.util.*;
public class Test1 {
public static String input;

public Test1(){
Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
String test = answer.next();
}
public static void initializeConstructor(){
 Test1 input = new Test1();
```

}

```
   public static void begin () {
   System.out.println("type:");

  initializeConstructor();

   System.out.println(input);
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    begin();
}
```

}

I am really new to learning java, my idea is that I can call the constructor to to start the scanner and it will spit back at me what I just typed. I am doing this so I can understand more about constructors in java. However when I run the following program, it just gives me "null". Like I said, i am preety new, so it may be a dumb question but any response would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code is exceedingly hard to read. Please fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll work on fixing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `input` is `null` (never assigned), change

```
String test = answer.next();
```

to

```
input = answer.next();
```

and your code will work. But `input` is `static` (it shouldn't be in real code, not if you're setting it in a constructor).

Comment: Thank you very much!! But what do you mean by "real code"?

Comment: I mean code that is for more than *I am doing this so I can understand more about constructors in java.*